# Fluent API - Many to Many with discriminator

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

### The situation

We have the following tables in MySQL (We cannot change the table layout or add new tables).

Table club:

```
Id 
---
```

Table club2category

```
ClubId | CategoryId
-------+-----------
```

Table category

```
Id | TypeIdentifier
---+----------------
```

There are currently two types of categories: AgeCategory and PriceCategory.

The following is the desired C# class structure.

Categories:

```csharp
public abstract class CategoryBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string TypeIdentifier { get; set; }

    public IList<Club> Clubs { get; set; }

    private protected CategoryBase() { }

    private protected CategoryBase(string typeIdentifier)
    {
        TypeIdentifier = typeIdentifier;
    }
}

public class AgeCategory
{
    private AgeCategory()
    {
    }

    public AgeCategory() : base("AGE")
    {
    }
}

public class PriceCategory : CategoryBase
{
    private PriceCategory()
    {
    }

    public PriceCategory() : base("PRICE")
    {
    }
}
```

Club:

```csharp
public class Club
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public IList<PriceCategory> PriceCategories { get; set; }
    
    public AgeCategory AgeCategory { get; set; }
    
    private Club()
    {
    }
}
```

And the linking table:

```csharp
public class ClubCategory
{
    public int ClubId { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public Club Club { get; set; }
    
    public CategoryBase Category { get; set; }
}
```

### The problem

However we are unsure as to how we would do the navigation property mapping using Fluent API as we have both a one to many and a many to many relation between what is basically table club and table category. Doing everything using database IDs only works fine however the benefit of using the Entity Framework is supposed to be not having to manually deal with the IDs.

### What I've tried

For testing I implemented two new classes and modified the club class like this:

```csharp
public class ClubAgeCategory : ClubCategory
{
    public virtual AgeCategory AgeCategory { get; set; }
}

public class ClubPriceCategory : ClubCategory
{
    public virtual PriceCategory PriceCategory { get; set; }
}

public class Club
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public IList<ClubPriceCategory> PriceCategoryLinkers { get; set; }
    
    public ClubAgeCategory AgeCategoryLinker { get; set; }
    
    private Club()
    {
    }
}
```

Then I tried to set up the mapping like this

```csharp
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // ....
    #region ClubAgeCategory

    modelBuilder.Entity<ClubAgeCategory>()
        .HasOne(cac => cac.Club)
        .WithOne(c => c.AgeCategoryLinker)
        .HasForeignKey<ClubAgeCategory>(cac => cac.ClubId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ClubAgeCategory>()
        .HasOne(cac => cac.AgeCategory)
        .WithMany(ac => ac.ClubLinkers)
        .HasForeignKey(cac => cac.CategoryId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    #endregion

    #region ClubPriceCategory

    modelBuilder.Entity<ClubPriceCategory>()
        .HasOne(cpc => cpc.Club)
        .WithMany(c => c.PriceCategoryLinkers)
        .HasForeignKey(cpc => cpc.ClubId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ClubPriceCategory>()
        .HasOne(cpc => cpc.PriceCategory)
        .WithMany(pc => pc.ClubLinkers)
        .HasForeignKey(cpc => cpc.CategoryId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    #endregion
    // ....
}
```

However now I would need to have additional discriminators in the club2category linking table to be able to distinguish between instances of `ClubAgeCategory` and `ClubPriceCategory`.

At this point I have no idea how you'd implement something like this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick practical solution to problems like this in general: If you already have an existing database layout setup, you can just scaffold the database.

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=myPassword;port=3306;database=So64662261" Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql -c Context -o Models --verbose
```

The scaffolder will generate the full code you need to use your existing database.

See [Reverse Engineering (scaffolding)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) for more information about scaffolding.

(Of course I can also provide you with a sample program to your actual question, if you don't want or can scaffold your existing database or it does not generate what you need for some reason. Just write a comment.)

Comment: Mhmm damn that's actually really interesting. I didn't know this was possible. I'll remember to use this approach it in the future however for now we already have like 99% of the mapping done. All that's missing is the mapping of this one relation described above :) So it would be preferable for us not to throw all the code away to use auto-generated mapping

Comment: @FrederikHoeft Just scaffold the database to some non-project folder and take a look at what Fluent API was generated for your case. If it solves your issue, just copy the parts over that you are missing. If it does not solve your problem, let me know and I take a closer look at what you wrote in the OP to post some sample code.